# Unity Configuration , config or not config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

What are advantages/ disadvantages of unity objects configuration mapping? in .config file vs mapping them in code ?

All examples I saw , were configured using .config file , but I've found one big disadvantage for me (spent 1.5 hr to realize why unity is fails) , after renaming Classes , the class name in config file doesn't renamed automatically , and unity fails.

What about advantages ?

How are you configure unity ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con (you have seen them):

- no IntelliSense
- no errors until runtime (no strong typing)

pro:

- you can change configuration without changing your code (after deploy)

Comment: @StringBuilder I prefer code - create Bootstrapper and register instances in container. How often you change implementation of some component of your site? Do you need to change it without recompiling your code? My answer is not often, if ever :)

Comment: xml configuration is good for something like setting connection strings, turning on tracing, changing logging settings, etc - things we manipulate after deploy. But setting-up dependency container is not one of such things.